# Where Are the Files in My Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: gcsfuse

I have mounted a bucket from my Google Cloud Storage account using gcsfuse. I'm surprised to see that none of the file from that bucket are now on my machine. This is a Google "instance" Debian 8, but I suspect the problem is more my not understanding how gcsfuse works. Should I *not see* my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue. The answer @jacobsa addressed the same issue for me.

Instead of mounting with

```
gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount
```

I used

```
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs my-bucket /path/to/mount
```

I also checked that the bucket is setup with the right permissions by adding myself as the *Owner* in *Edit bucket permissions*

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running into the issues with [implicit directories](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#implicit-directories).